# How to split string with multiple delimiters in Python?

Tags: python, regex

My First String

```
xxx.xxx.com-bonding_err_bond0-if_eth2-d.rrd.csv
```

But I want to result like this below

```
bonding_err_bond0-if_eth2
```

I try some code but seems not work correctly

```
csv = "xxx.xxx.com-bonding_err_bond0-if_eth2-d.rrd.csv"

x = csv.rsplit('.', 4)[2]

print(x)
```

But Result that I get is **com-bonding_err_bond0-if_eth2-d** But my purpose is **bonding_err_bond0-if_eth2**

Comment: you could split the output again on `-` and join the required slice: `x = '-'.join(x.split('-')[1:-1])`

Comment: Are you needing to search for similar strings which may have different interface id's? Will the pattern change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you got the answer, but if you want a generic method for any string data you can do this:

In this way you wont be restricted to one string and you can loop the data as well.

```
csv = "xxx.xxx.com-bonding_err_bond0-if_eth2-d.rrd.csv"

first_index = csv.find("-")
second_index = csv.find("-d")

result = csv[first_index+1:second_index]
print(result)
# OUTPUT:
# bonding_err_bond0-if_eth2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use the solution apart from regex,
You can break the solution into a smaller part to understand better and learn about `join` if you are not aware of it. It will come in handy.

```
solution= '-'.join(csv.split('.', 4)[2].split('-')[1:3])
```

Thanks,
Shashank

Answer (score 1):

You can just separate the string with `-`, remove the beginning and end, and then join them back into a string.

```
csv = "xxx.xxx.com-bonding_err_bond0-if_eth2-d.rrd.csv"

x = '-'.join(csv.split('-')[1:-1])
```

### Output

```
>>> csv
>>> bonding_err_bond0-if_eth2
```